# Login to both CakePHP and vbulletin

Tags: cakephp, authentication, vbulletin

I'm looking to get a single sign on set-up between a cakePHP (1.3) app and a vBulletin (4.0.2) forum.

I've managed to get so far with it, i.e I've been able to get Auth to use the vB *user* table to let people login, and that works pretty well - the issue now is getting the two different systems to share a session so that users can pass between the main cake site, and the vB forum, without losing their session and being logged out.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your CakePHP app uses the same session cookie name as vBulletin. You can change this in `app/Config/core.php` under the `Session.cookie` key.
- It has to be as the `session_name()` in vBulletin uses

If this is done, you have the same data in the global `$_SESSION` variable in both systems. You also have to make sure they run under the same top-level domain, so cookies can be read. Also, the cookie has to be a wildcard one, meaning that the `session.cookie_domain` has to start with a ".".

For example: `.your-domain.com` will allow `cakephp.your-domain.com` and `forum.your-domain.com` to access the same session cookie.